# How to remove part of h1 tag and use it somewhere else leaving h1 untouched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following tag :

```
<h1><span>FOO</span> Rest of my title</h1>
```

I'd like to retrieve "Rest of my title" to append it somewhere else (without the span); but also, i'd like the h1 to stay the same (not having the span removed).

What i'm doing so far is :

```
var h1 = $("h1");
var result = $(h1).find("span").remove().end().text();
alert(result);
```

=> Will turn

```
<h1><span>FOO</span> Rest of my title</h1>
```

into

```
<h1>Rest of my title</h1>
```

I think i'm modifying the H1 instead of retrieving its value for further manipulation.

How could I achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. I'd suggest chaining a `.clone()` after `$(h1)` so that you don't manipulate the item on the page, but rather a temporary copy of it.

```js
var h1 = $("h1");
var result = $(h1).clone().find("span").remove().end().text();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span>FOO</span> Rest of my title</h1>
```

Comment: It works, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just clone the h1 object and do your job

```
var h1 = $("h1").clone();
var result = $(h1).find("span").remove().end().text();
alert(result);
```